# How to redirect url included string in htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

I need a rewrite rule in htaccess file. I have the following URL:

```
https://example.com/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.another.com%2Fcatalog%2F%3Fq%3Dhello+friend
```

I need to redirect it to the URL output excatlly like this:

```
https://newpage.com/3333333?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.another.com%2Fcatalog%2F%3Fq%3Dhello+friend
```

The **https://example.com/** will be replaced by **https://newpage.com/3333333?url=**. And the following query(whatever or anything) will be keep same in the new link.

I have tried many times but the output is **https://newpage.com/3333333?url=https://www.another.com/catalog/catalog/?q=hello friend** :(

My code 1:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/?$ [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com/?$
   RewriteRule (.*)$ https://newpage.com/3333333?url=$1 [R=302,L]
```

My code 2:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/?$ [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com/?$
   RewriteRule (.*)$ https://newpage.com/3333333?url=%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Can you help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code have you tried? Is the original URL-path (that contains the encoded URL) entirely variable? "but the output is" - so you are getting a redirect? By default, the original URL in your example should result in an automatic 404. (?)

Comment: @MrWhite I try two code but not excatly what I want:
**Code 1:**
`RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/?$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com/?$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://newpage.com/3333333?url=$1 [R=302,L]`

**Code 2:**
`RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/?$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com/?$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://newpage.com/3333333?url=%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]`